# IntelliJ IDEA plugin for JavaFX Scene Builder drag & drop stops working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm working with IDEA Ultimate 2016.3, Scene Builder 2.0-b20 on MacOS Sierra.

The drag & drop feature, dragging the controls from the left side panel into the scene seems to stop working after a while. I have to restart IDEA when this happens before they start working again.

Any pointers on why this happens or how to resolve it without having to re-start IDEA are appreciated.

I've attached a screenshot in case the explanation wasn't good enough.

[image: Scene Builder]

Comment: Workaround: Use standalone Gluon Scene Builder.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the exact same problem. 
This solution worked for me.  In the 'gradle' option at the right vertical toolbar of the IDE.
select the project.

build->clean.

Each time it happened, I did the same.
It reduced the hassle of restarting the ide.

Comment: Thanks, I would never have figured that out. 2 1/2 years later and this bug is still present in the latest version.

Comment: Wow. Thank you man you saved my day. I never know this is related to the build directory.